# Difference between navbar bootstrap in same firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I created a page that has a navbar from bootstrap 3.

In firefox v.37.0.2 the navbar is like this:

[image]

But in another computer that it has same firefox (v.37.0.2), the navbar is ok:
[image]

Also the page and navbar is ok in chrome v.42 and IE v.11.

Why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but couple of crosschecks you can do

1. Check screen resolution of another computer
2. Check if you are testing in already zoom in browser (Press Ctrl + 0 to make it normal)
3. Very least but cache could be one problem